# How to hide specific field by User Group on a django admin

Tags: python, django, admin

i want to hide a specific line of my Django Admin Model by permission or Group

My models.py

```python
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default='actus')
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/thumbs', blank=True, null=True, default="media/thumbs/default.jpg")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post", kwargs={"slug": self.slug, "category": self.category})
```

My Model admin

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.db.migrations.graph import Node
from django.utils.regex_helper import Group

from .....models import Post


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'date', 'is_verified')
    list_filter = ('date', 'author', 'is_verified')


admin.site.site_header = 'Staff Dashboard'
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

My django admin page
[Django admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXl2c.png)

If someone has an idea

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Please also share the model admin.

Comment: I just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two `ModelForm`s: one with the `is_verified` option, and one without, so:

```
# app_name/forms.py

from django import forms
from app_name.models import Post

class NormalUserPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ['is_verified']

class AdminUserPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

then we can override the `get_form` method of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
# app_name/admin.py

from app_name.forms import NormalUserPostForm, AdminUserPostForm

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'date', 'is_verified')
    list_filter = ('date', 'author', 'is_verified')
    form = NormalUserPostForm

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            kwargs['form'] = AdminUserPostForm
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)


admin.site.site_header = 'Staff Dashboard'
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

You can change the condition to `request.user.has_perm('some_permission')` to check for a certain permission instead.

Comment: But how to include a ModelForm inside the django admin panel ?

Comment: @Graven: I'm not following, normally that is the form that Django will use in the admin. Depending on the user it will use the `NormalUserPostForm`, or the `AdminUserPostForm`.

Comment: by default is use the integrate form inside django admin view not on custom view

Comment: @Graven: but this *is* the django admin, that is why you need to speciify a `form = ...` and the `get_form` of the `PostAdmin`, not a class-based view.

Comment: can i have an example please ? :)